# Control the ability to change member variable via member function in C++ class

Tags: c++, class, constants

Consider

```
class foo
{
 int a;
 int b;
public:
  void f1();
  void f2();
  void f3();
};
```

Is there support in C++ to allow `a` be mutable in `f2()` and `f3()` but `const` in `f1()`, while keeping `b` mutable everywhere?

EDIT: The example above is illustration of question, but I am looking for if there is generalized solution to write access control

Comment: I guess it goes without saying that you don't want the nonsense answer?

Comment: Make `f1` a `const` member function and declare `b` `mutable`?

Comment: How about shadowing it at the beginning of the `f1` via `auto const &a = this->a;`?

Comment: I was hoping for more readable solution, i.e, declaration such as `class foo { int a-> { const in f1, f2} };` where it becomes very clear just by looking at the definition of class

Comment: Why would someone reading the declaration care about such implementation details that are in no way relevant to the member function's contract?

Comment: You want your implementation details to be included in the class definition? That's not a good idea.

Comment: Add comments in your source code for future yourself or other developers updating it.

Comment: I thought c++ allowed to show some implementation detail by letting programmers add `const` qualifier. Adding comments does not make it a binding contract

Comment: @user6386155 - The const qualifier on a member function is not an implementation detail. It's a contract involving the operation and the state of the class object as a whole. Member specific stuff like you are after *are* implementation details. And it's quite likely to cause leaky abstractions. Imagine a client relies on you not changing `a`. What happens when you need to modify it when the code evolves? You broke your client's code. And don't get me wrong, `mutable` can be criticized the exact same way, and is usually best used judiciously.

Comment: Use naming! If you change the name of `f1()` to `modify_b_only()`, most people would assume that it doesn't modify `a`. Probably even including the future maintainers of the class.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible using const member function and mutable attribute :

```
#include <iostream>
class foo
{
 int a;
 mutable int b;
public:
    foo() {
        a = 10;
        b = 20;
    }
    void f1() const{
        // std::cout << ++a << std::endl; // this won't compile
        std::cout << a << std::endl;
        std::cout << ++b << std::endl;  // This compile despite f1 being const because b is declared as mutable
    }
    void f2() {
        std::cout << ++a << std::endl;// This compile because both a and b are mutable in f2
        std::cout << ++b << std::endl;   
    }
    void f3() {
        std::cout << ++a << std::endl;// This compile because both a and b are mutable in f3
        std::cout << ++b << std::endl;   
    }
};
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";
    foo f;
    f.f1();
    f.f2();
    f.f3();
}
```

Comment: This is (edit: was) the exact reverse of the question. The asker wanted `b` mutable everywhere and `a` mutable in `f3` and `f2` but not `f1`.

Comment: ... even so the principle is still the same and this clearly answers the question.

Comment: `not` (*this* answer)

Comment: @super That is true (and I did not mean to imply the answer was fundamentally wrong), but the answer might as well be edited to fit the question.

Comment: Problem is that it doesn't scale. And the granularity isn't all that great (just try adding a third variable and make it const only in `f2`). I think the OP wanted something else.

Comment: @StoryTeller Then the OP should probably improve the question. This answer fully answers the current question.

Comment: @StoryTeller You're right but this wasn't the question. We can't assume / guess OP's intention if it is not stated.